# How to update columns with different values when there are duplicate identifier values

Tags: oracle

I have a table with definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id NUMBER(19,0),
    nam VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);
```

and the data
[image: init]

I have to set the same `ID`s for the entries who have the same `EMAIL`.

How can I do it?
I am using the oracle 18g database.

expected results

[image: desired]

Comment: "I have to make the ids of the entries same who have the same email" - what does that mean? What is desired result?

Comment: Please also include the expected output.  Which duplicate is the master version?

Comment: Furthermore, ID is *usually* unique; there are two rows with ID = 5 in your sample table. Is that correct?

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have the same id for the matching emails:

```
MERGE INTO test_table tt
USING (SELECT MIN(ID)
            , email
         FROM test_table 
        GROUP BY email) mails
   ON (tt.email = mails.email)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tt.id = mails.id;
```